# Clarification of term in graph theory - about star polygon graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology, definition

I was reading about star polygon graphs from the following link:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarPolygon.html.

As far as I noticed I felt that whenever $d$ is a proper divisor of $n$, then we get $d$ copies of cycle of length $n/d$
where $~$ $d<\lfloor n\rfloor$. Is my observation correct? Kindly rectify me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is consistent with the MathWorld entry.

However, it should be noted that not everyone uses this interpretation. In particular, Grünbaum and others (like me) take the model regular $\{n/d\}$-gon to have its $k$-th vertex (starting at the $0$-th) at coordinates
$$\left(\;\cos \frac{2\pi dk}{n}\;,\; \sin\frac{2\pi dk}{n} \;\right)$$ 
With this view, a $\{12/4\}$-gon, for instance, isn't a *compound* of four separate triangles in the MathWorld sense; it's a *dodecagon* that wraps around a single triangular cycle four times. See some related thoughts [in this answer to the question "What is a Hexagon?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208972/409).